# loop trough elements in API JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm trying to print all "name" values in HTML from my API JSON file, i'm pretty new to javascript and jquery, how could i do this?
Here's my JSON file, all the {}, have the same structure but with different information.

```
{
"launches": [
{
"id": 2036,
"name": "Electron | Don't Stop Me Now",
"windowstart": "June 11, 2020 04:43:00 UTC",
"windowend": "June 11, 2020 06:32:00 UTC",
},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple for loop or forEach loop...

```
  // json data

  let data = {
    "launches": [
        {
            "id": 2036,
            "name": "Electron | Don't Stop Me Now",
            "windowstart": "June 11, 2020 04:43:00 UTC",
            "windowend": "June 11, 2020 06:32:00 UTC",
        },
        {
            "id": 2037,
            "name": "Don't Stop Me Now",
            "windowstart": "June 11, 2020 04:43:00 UTC",
            "windowend": "June 11, 2020 06:32:00 UTC",
        }
    ]
};

// function for handling data manipulation 
function printNames() {
    let parsed = '';// temp variable for storing it as string
    for (i = 0; i < data.launches.length; i++) { //iterate through each array item to fin require info
        parsed += data.launches[i].id + ' ' + data.launches[i].name + "\n";
    }
    console.log(parsed)
    let elem = document.getElementById('container');
    elem.innerHTML = parsed; //Append it to container
}
printNames();
```

Comment: Hey! thanks, but i can't manage to make a new line after every iteration of the for loop

Comment: try giving <br> instead of \n inside loop

Comment: @AgussMasco or you could change the elem.innerHTML to innerText and it will work fine... If u found the answer useful please upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can loop through an array of objects and print a specific value of object

```
jsonObj.launches.forEach(item => console.log(item.name))
```

Comment: How could i instead of console.log, show the names in a html doc?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plain Javascript. You could do something like this.

```
var data = [{
    "launches": [
    {
    "id": 2036,
    "name": "Electron | Don't Stop Me Now",
    "windowstart": "June 11, 2020 04:43:00 UTC",
    "windowend": "June 11, 2020 06:32:00 UTC",
    }]
   }];

    var names = data.map(i=>i.name);

    names.forEach(i=>{
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     div.innerText = i;
     document.body.appendChild(div);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
launches.map((item,index)=>{
return <h3 key={index}>{item.name}</h3>
})
```

it will loop through all the values of your array and print your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_object = {
    "launches": [
    {
    "id": 2036,
    "name": "Electron | Don't Stop Me Now",
    "windowstart": "June 11, 2020 04:43:00 UTC",
    "windowend": "June 11, 2020 06:32:00 UTC",
    }]};

for(var i=0; i<my_object.launches.length;i++){
    console.log(my_object.launches[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do what you're suggesting.
(I wasn't sure what you meant by "print ... in HTML", so I just added each `name` string to an existing list in the HTML code.)

```js
// An array that might be a JSON response from an HTTP request
const players = [
  { name: "Chris", score: 20, winner: false },
  { name: "Anne", score: 22, winner: true },
  { name: "Taylor", score: 14, winner: false }
];

// You can loop through an array with `for...of`
for(let player of players){

  // You can access a property of "player" with `player.whateverThePropIsCalled`
  addListItem(player.name);
}

// You can do whatever you want with the name, such as appending it to a list
function addListItem(name){
  const textNode = document.createTextNode(name);
  const listItem = document.createElement("LI");
  listItem.appendChild(textNode);

  const list = document.getElementById("list");
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

```html
<ol id="list"></ol>
```